# Login com redirect

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um form de login rodando com JQuery + PHP, estou implmentando a opção para redirecionar baseado na url que quero receber via GET, conforme abaixo:

```
https://pt-br.example.com/?redirect=https://blog.example.com/
```

Problema é que não recebo recebo via GET a variável redirect

Método Login

```
    private function Login() {

$Session -> session_token  = (string) $Functions -> ClearVariable($_POST['tokenForm']); 
$Session -> CheckSessionTokenForm();

$this->Email = (string) mb_strtolower($Functions -> ClearVariable($_POST['loginEmail']));
$this->Password = (string) $Functions -> ClearVariable($_POST['loginPsw']);

if(isset($_GET['redirect']))
{
    $this->Location = $Functions -> ClearVariable($_GET['redirect']);
}
else
{
    $this->Location = 'dashboard/'; 
}
```

... 
}

JQuery Post

```
$('button[type="submit"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).closest('form').attr('data-url');
    var formId = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    var iBtn = $(this).children('i').attr('id');

    $.ajax({            
        url: url,           
        data: $('#'+formId).serialize(),
        dataType:"json",
        type:"post",
        success: function(data){
            switch(data.status) {
                case 'location':  
                    window.location.href = data.flag;
                    break;  
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

Uso PHP com JQuery post, pode ser por causa do JQuery post?

Comment: O que aparece quando ao fazer o `echo`? Você está tratando de todos os caracteres no valor de `redirect`? Pois deveria ser algo como `redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.example.com%2F `

Comment: Não aparece nada, o atributo $this->Location está vazio

Comment: Tem como colocar o código JS e o PHP completo na pergunta então?

Comment: `$this->Location` é sempre igual a `dashboard/` então?

Comment: Não, tenho outras páginas que o usuário pode clicar no link entrar e ser direcionado para a página de login com a url de origm, quando o usuário acessar a página de login direto será direcionado para dashboard/

Comment: Mas se você não recebe os dados com o `$_GET`, o `isset($_GET['redirect'])` iria sempre retornar `False`. Então você deve estar recebendo o valor corretamente, mas tratando de forma errada. O que é `$Functions -> ClearVariable`?

Comment: Eu removi a condição isset para verificar se estava recebendo algum valor, e mesmo assim não recebi nada. ClearVariable é para limpar entrada de usuário, evitar ataque.

Comment: O que acontece se você colocar `echo json_encode($_GET)` e no JS, ao invés de fazer o `window.location`, faça `console.log(data)`. Lembre-se de finalizar a execução do PHP após esse `echo`, com `return` ou `exit()`.

Comment: Vou testar do jeito que você colocou.. Acabei de criar da seguinte maneira:  $Location = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if($Location !== '/') { $Location = str_replace("/?redirect=","",$Location);   } else { $Location = 'dashboard/';  } e criei um input hidden no form com o Location.. e vou testar.. Funcionando ou não testarei do jeito que você colocou, serve para conhecimento. :)

Answer (score 1):

pega a pagina passada pela url com $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] armazena em uma variável, se passar pelas suas condições você leva o usuário pra página que você quer

Comment: Com echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],  aparece /?redirect=https://blog.example.com/